# PHPlist & new posts notification?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I know there are plugins out there for integrating the user base & sign-up, but are there any for using PHPlist to automatically send out newsletters of new posts?

I'm really trying to avoid a from-scratch solution here, though if nothing is 'ready made' I'd appreciate any pointers or head starts ;)

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but maybe some useful info. I just saw this post on my RSS reader this morning talking about newsletters. http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/what-why-and-how-tos-of-email-newsletter-for-your-wordpress-blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know of a plugin that does that but if you take a look at [**WP PHPList plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/phplist-form-integration/) or more specifically the way it [**Interacts with phplist**](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/phplist-form-integration/trunk/phplist.php?rev=227427#L136) using PHP CURL, it logs in to phplist as admin and save cookie using `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and then simulates a post to subscriber form. So maybe going in that route you can do the same and simulate a post to 
send mail form.

then all that is left is to hook you function to these hooks:

```
add_action('new_to_publish', 'send_new_post_mail');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'send_new_post_mail');
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'send_new_post_mail');
add_action('private_to_publish', 'send_new_post_mail');
add_action('future_to_publish', 'send_new_post_mail');
```

I know its not a complete solution but should give you a jump start.